# How to retrieve form values using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How do I to retrieve the name and value from form elements?

e.g.: I should have an output like `id=110kgod, checkbox=cancel, name=aj, age=23`
I have heard of serialize but can that be applied?

```
<DIV style="BORDER-BOTTOM: blue 2px ridge; BORDER-LEFT: blue 2px ridge; WIDTH: 1000px; BORDER-TOP: blue 2px ridge; BORDER-RIGHT: blue 2px ridge" id=0_212099594_990000 class=mid>
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%" align=center>
    <TBODY>
        <TR vAlign=top align=middle width="100%" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0" border="0">
            <TD width="15%"><H4>ID</H4></TD>
            <TD width="5%"></TD>
            <TD width="30%" align=left><INPUT onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'" class=input_0_212099594_990000 onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccc'" value=110KG0D name=ow_id> </TD>
            <TD width="19%"></TD>
            <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM: black 1px solid; BORDER-LEFT: black 1px solid; BORDER-TOP: black 1px solid; BORDER-RIGHT: black 1px solid" class=radiobutton width="20%" align=middle>YES<INPUT class=0_212099594_990000 disabled value=YES type=radio name=0_212099594_990000 jQuery172033007169320727875="2">NO<INPUT class=0_212099594_990000 disabled value=NO type=radio name=0_212099594_990000 jQuery172033007169320727875="3">MAYBE<INPUT class=0_212099594_990000 value=MAYBE CHECKED type=radio name=0_212099594_990000 jQuery172033007169320727875="4"></TD>
            <TD width="5%" align=right><BUTTON style="BORDER-BOTTOM: medium none; BORDER-LEFT: medium none; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white; BORDER-TOP: medium none; BORDER-RIGHT: medium none" onclick="javascript:ShowHide('0_212099594_990000')"><IMG src="../images/delete.png"></BUTTON> 
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="98%" align=center>
    <TBODY>
        <TR vAlign=top align=left>
            <TD style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 1em" width="9%" align=middle><FONT color=black size=2><B>NAME</B></FONT></TD>
            <TD class=input_0_212099594_990000 width="8%" align=left><SELECT name=bsn_code> <OPTION selected value=a>A</OPTION> <OPTION value=B>B</OPTION> <OPTION value=C>C</OPTION> <OPTION value=D>D</OPTION> <OPTION value=OS>OS</OPTION></SELECT> </TD>
            <TD vAlign=top width="10%" align=middle><FONT color=black size=2><B>Age</B> </FONT></TD>
            <TD vAlign=top width="10%" align=left><INPUT onblur="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'" class=input_0_212099594_990000 onfocus="this.style.backgroundColor='#ccc'" size=15 value=23 name=osi_cd> </TD>
            <TD width="1%"></TD>
            <TD class=input_0_212099594_990000 width="10%">22</TD>
            <TD class=input_0_212099594_990000 width="30%"></TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>                        
</DIV>
```

Comment: 90's flashbacks

Comment: my esteemed peer is making a funny comment on how your html is rather "old-school". Table layout, inline styling, width attributes, etc.

Comment: just to clarify, you want to grab the name and value from every tag inside of the div? Only this div (id=212)?

Comment: `$('div').find(':input').serialize()`. Why are you guys bashing his markup? Acting like 12 year olds right now.

Comment: Or http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject

Comment: @lbstr: Also the UPPER CASE tags.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I didn't think it was thaaat bad. Also, you should make an answer out of your comment so he has somethign to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize will give you the name/value of inputs within a given element/form

Leaving you with a string like `osi_cd=21&bsn_code=[SELECTED.VALUE]&....` essentially a key/value pair based on input name and input value. Input type I believe is irrelevant with serialize.

if Your want to capture more than just that you will need to cycle through the elements in the form manually in a matter of speaking, then build your own string to post with based off of that.

On a side note, your HTML isn't very valid, and may cause some issues on some browsers especially some older ones.. all attributes custom or otherwise should always be lowercase and and enclosed in double quotes

example:
`<input name="something" class="colorme" id="whatever" rel="something_else">` then also depending on your choice of HTML formatting ie: XHTML, HTML5, other. You have to compensate for whats valid with those. W3C has a good validation page that you can feed a URL to and it will validate the HTML (this is good if you want the search engines to not penalize you and give you a lower index, also can save some headache when using javascript/jquery in the future)

Overall back to the point though, you can mimic serialize through a bit of custom coding. Such as looping over elements within a given containing element or form tag and within that loop build out a string that would better suit your needs for posting.

Alternatively you could also use "hidden" elements to run serialize over that would get the pairs from each and build the string accordingly. In the end though its not going to be something simile as serialize and pass the data, some custom logic will need to be applied somewhere. To work with the data accordingly. Personally I would build a multidimensional array to then post based off of what I am gathering from your post is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ow_id = $('#ow_id').val();
    var bsn_code = $('#bsn_code').val();
    var osi_cd = $('#osi_cd').val();
    alert('ID: ' + ow_id + ', NAME: ' + bsn_code + ', AGE: ' + osi_cd);
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/collabcoders/NQ5jf/

Comment: Why do this when that's what serialize does? It takes the `name` of an element and gives you the `value` of the element., so you end up with a string that looks like `name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3`. This way we can do `$_POST['name1'];` and get `value1` This method is unraveling the wheel.

Comment: It wasnt specified that this was for a form post so I wasn't sure.   This method he do can something with the values and custom attributes.

Comment: Also the elements are using custom attributes like age.   seralize will only get the input value and not other custom attributes

Comment: Imagine I do not have a form just the div. serialize from what i read works only with a form

Comment: @Haran Murthy - I've already responded in a comment and told you how to serialize form elements `even when they're not in a form`. Try it yourself -> `console.log($('div').find(':input').serialize());`